# In python, what is super(classItSelf) doing?

Tags: python, oop

In python, what is super(classItSelf) doing?

I have a project to work on has code such as this:

```
class Tele(TcInterface):

    _signal = signal.SIGUSR1

    def __init__(self):
        super(Tele, self).__init__()
        self._c = None
```

What is this line doing?

```
super(Tele, self).__init__()
```

I am a cpp java code, Really got confused about python stuff.

Comment: What questions do you have that are not answered by [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super)?

Comment: ```Tele``` is a subclass of ```TcInterface```.  ```Tele``` overrides ```__init___``` and ```super(Tele, self).__init__()``` executes ```__init___``` in ```TcInterface``` which is ```Tele```'s parent (super).  If you want to *extend* a method that was inherited, you can use ```super``` to execute that method from the parent  then add  more instructions/statements to extend it.

Comment: Similar to, if not duplicate of, [Understanding Python super() with __init__() methods](http://stackoverflow.com/q/576169/2823755)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This calls the `__init__()` function (constructor) of the super/parent class (`TclInterface`). This is often necessary, as the superclass constructor is otherwise overridden by `__init__()` in the subclass.

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass at least `self` to `__init__`.

python is different from some traditional OOP languages, which will handle `self` or `this` or whatever name you give to the current instance automatically for you.

in python, `self` is exposed, even in constructor, so that you need to pass in and reference it yourself. and this `super(...)` here, it basically looks for a proxy, which represents all super classes, and `super(...).__init__` is referencing the constructors from the super classes. it's the same concept as you call `super()` in C++ or Java.

please reference doc for more: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super